# Disable Javascript in fourm posts - bbPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, security, bbpress

Currently users are allowed to use `Javascript` in `bbPress` posts. I would like to disable this for security reasons but cannot find the "off" switch.

I have looked for `plugins`, `settings` and other `questions` to no avail.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.magpress.com/blog/how-to-disable-bbpress-plugins-styles-and-js-in-wordpress-page

Comment: That is for disabling bbPress stuff on other pages except bbpress. I am looking for a solution inside of bbPress and only for the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to write some code, you should use html_encode() on all your outputs. Ideally you would want a serious whitelist sanitizer and encoder, such as https://code.google.com/p/reform/. Using this might be too technical though. I'm sure you'll know though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have not had time to work on this project. I will definitely keep it in mind when I go to test it. Thanks!